# Unique constraint on Distinct select in Oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a data processor that would create a table from a select query.

```
<_config:table definition="CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE (PRODUCT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL, STORE NUMBER NOT NULL, USD NUMBER(20, 5), 
                            CAD NUMBER(20, 5), Description varchar(5), ITEM_ID VARCHAR(256), PRIMARY KEY (ITEM_ID))" name="TEMP_TABLE"/>
```

and the select query is

```
<_config:query sql="SELECT  DISTINCT ce.PRODUCT_ID, ce.STORE, op.USD ,op.CAD, o.Description, ce.ITEM_ID 
                FROM PRICE op, PRODUCT ce, STORE ex, OFFER o, SALE t 
                where op.ITEM_ID = ce.ITEM_ID and ce.STORE = ex.STORE 
                and ce.PRODUCT_ID = o.PRODUCT_ID and o.SALE_ID IN (2345,1234,3456) and t.MEMBER = ce.MEMBER"/>
```

When I run that processor, I get an unique constraint error, though I have a distinct in my select statement.

I tried with CREATE TABLE AS (SELECT .....) its creating fine.

Is it possible to get that error? I'm doing a batch execute so not able to find the individual record.

Answer (score 3):

The `select distinct` applies to the entire row, not to each column individually.  So, two rows could have the same value of `item_id` but be different in the other columns.

The ultimate fix might be to have a `group by item_id` in the query, instead of `select distinct`.  That would require other changes to the logic.  Another possibility would be to use `row_number()` in a subquery and select the first row.